# How to install LXDM instead of GDM3?

Tags: debian, software-installation, apt

I'm running Debian Wheezy and my default Display Manager is GDM3, and I would like to replace it with LXDM. The problem is that I'm trying to run `# apt-get install lxde` and it's not working, what am I doing wrong?

My `/etc/apt/sources.list` is:

```
deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux testing _Wheezy_ - Official Snapshot i386 DVD Binar$

deb http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian wheezy main
deb-src http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main

deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like lxdm is not present in Debian wheezy; at least, it's not included in any packages according to the results of a [package contents search](http://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=contents&keywords=lxdm&mode=filename&suite=testing&arch=any). You may need to install it from source or from a third-party repository.

If you did install an alternate display manager via dpkg, however, you would want to run something like `dpkg-reconfigure gdm3` to get a display-manager chooser.

Debian's display manager startup scripts look at the contents of `/etc/X11/default-display-manager` to see whether they should run. If you install one manually, you will probably need to empty that file and add your own startup script.