# Debian E: unable to locate package

Tags: linux, debian, apt

I am attempting to install the `lxdm` package for debian (wheezy). Running `apt-get update` does not yield any errors, and my sources.list file is as follows:

```
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main

deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates

deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian wheezy-updates
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/
```

Comment: Please would you show the command you use and the error reported

Comment: Actually, the answer you need is [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48450/how-to-install-lxdm-instead-of-gdm3)

Answer (score 1):

`lxdm` is in Debian unstable, but not in Wheezy. You might be able to backport it, though.

```
apt-cache policy lxdm
lxdm:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.5.0-3
  Version table:
     0.5.0-3 0
         50 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ unstable/main amd64 Packages
```

The build depends of `lxdm` are given as:

```
apt-cache showsrc lxdm
...
Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 9), intltool, iso-codes, libck-connector-dev, libgtk2.0-dev, libpam0g-dev, libx11-dev, libxmu-dev, pkg-config, dh-systemd, po-debconf
```

These are all in Debian wheezy, except for `dh-systemd`, which is in wheezy-backports. Try typing to see the available versions:

```
apt-cache policy debhelper intltool iso-codes libck-connector-dev libgtk2.0-dev libpam0g-dev libx11-dev libxmu-dev pkg-config dh-systemd po-debconf
```